# Javascript in Qualtrics to enable the back button

Tags: javascript, qualtrics

What Javascript can I use in my Qualtrics survey to enable the back button for a question?  I already have it enabled for the entire survey, but, Qualtrics has disabled it for one particular question, and, they said the only way to have it enabled for this question is through javascript

Comment: I don't think you can. If you have the previous button enabled and it doesn't display on a page it is because it won't work on that page because of survey logic. Usually this occurs on the first page of a block.

Comment: Thank you - maybe I'll try adjusting blocks to see if that will help

Comment: That worked - I just adjusted the question flow within the blocks.  Thanks!

Comment: @CElev You should post an answer and accept it, as to not leave the question open.